# Testing using Plink.exe to connect to SSH in C#

Tags: c#, ssh, automation, putty, plink

Im trying to connect to a unix terminal via plink.exe. The goal is so that I can read the text back into a string.

My dilema is that the bank I work for uses an old as400 type system that we normally access through putty. I'm trying to develop an automation suite that will interface with the system and run jobs and analyse the outputs etc.

So I figured I'd use plink through C#. If I run the code via Command prompt I get (roughly) the text I need back. However im suffering a problem in my C# code in that it just hangs and I never get a reponse.

What I want is like this:

Connect to server
Input command
Read back screen
//More Commands etc

Here is my code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd");
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process process = Process.Start(psi);
        string cmdForTunnel = @"c:\putty\plink -ssh jonkers@bankhq -pw automationhero";
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmdForTunnel);
       // process.WaitForExit();
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        //DoBusinessLogic();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("logout");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        if (process.HasExited)
        {
            process.Close();
            process.Dispose();
        } 
    }
}
```

Im not really sure where the issues lie because as I say ive tested in using plink through command line, but with my solution above it just hangs. Ive tried using other peoples solutions on stackoverflow but none of them seem to work for me as I keep getting this hang. And tips would be much appreciated.

EDIT

I've now decided to use the Renci Sharp SSH library and have build my own framework around this. It works much better.

Comment: I suppose `ReadToEnd` will block until plink is exited by the remote host... You should try to step through the code (F10) to determine where you really *hang*

Comment: Yeah I tried that... it just goes on forever. Im not sure using Plink.exe is even the best method here. Maybe using SSH directly is better.

Comment: Well there are a few solutions... Implementing a SSH client is on of the harder ones :D Do you *need* to use a `.Net` environment? Also you still did not tell us **where exactly** your code hangs!

Comment: Preferably .net our development manager is a microsoft fanboy so wont let me use Java which is probably the language im more familiar with.
The code hangs on the line: string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Comment: OK, well you can do this in .net perfectly fine. First of all you have to start to inmplement the read write asynchronously...Essentially run the Read (use Read instead of ReadToEnd or ReadLine) on another thread and signal your writing thread (may be the original thread) to send the logout signal once you got all the data you need. You may want to check out how to read processes asynchronously

Comment: Ok thanks MrPaulch I shall look into this. Thanks for taking the time to help me. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I just wanted to test `plink` myself and well it's result were pretty pleasing.

As I said in the comments you can't use `ReadToEnd` **before** you send the **exit** command, unless you want to **block** your *current* Thread.

Actually you could just send a bunch of commands (including the `exit` or `logout`) before engaging the `ReadToEnd`, but I did suggest to do the Read asynchrounusly as it is more robust.

Now there are a few ways to do async reading of a stream.

---

The `Process` class actually provides `Events` that are raised on incoming data. You could create *handlers* for those `Events`.
These Events are:

- `OutputDataReceived`
- `ErrorDataReceived`

Their event handlers provide strings containing the data.

---

You could use the `BeginRead` of the `StreamReader` instances of stdout/stdin.

But here I provide a code sample that does it in a more crude way using simple multi-threading:

```
  public string RequestInfo(string remoteHost, string userName, string password, string[] lstCommands) {
        m_szFeedback = "Feedback from: " + remoteHost + "\r\n";

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = PLINK_PATH, // A const or a readonly string that points to the plink executable
            Arguments = String.Format("-ssh {0}@{1} -pw {2}", userName, remoteHost, password),
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process p = Process.Start(psi);

        m_objLock = new Object();
        m_blnDoRead = true;

        AsyncReadFeedback(p.StandardOutput); // start the async read of stdout
        AsyncReadFeedback(p.StandardError); // start the async read of stderr

        StreamWriter strw = p.StandardInput;

        foreach (string cmd in lstCommands)
        {
            strw.WriteLine(cmd); // send commands 
        }
        strw.WriteLine("exit"); // send exit command at the end

        p.WaitForExit(); // block thread until remote operations are done
        return m_szFeedback;
    }

    private String m_szFeedback; // hold feedback data
    private Object m_objLock; // lock object
    private Boolean m_blnDoRead; // boolean value keeping up the read (may be used to interrupt the reading process)

    public void AsyncReadFeedback(StreamReader strr)
    {
        Thread trdr = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(__ctReadFeedback));
        trdr.Start(strr);
    }
    private void __ctReadFeedback(Object objStreamReader)
    {
        StreamReader strr = (StreamReader)objStreamReader; 
        string line;          
        while (!strr.EndOfStream && m_blnDoRead) 
        {
            line = strr.ReadLine();
            // lock the feedback buffer (since we don't want some messy stdout/err mix string in the end)
            lock (m_objLock) { m_szFeedback += line + "\r\n"; }
        }
    }
```

So if you want to get the contents of the user directory of a remote host call:

```
String feedback = RequestInfo("remote.ssh.host.de", "user", "password", new string[] { "ls -la" });
```

Obviously you substitute your own address, credentials and command-list.

Also you might want to clean the output string. e.G. in my case the commands I send to the remotehost are echoed into the output and thus appear in the return string.

Comment: Thanks for going that extra mile to help me out! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is very helpful. Tried many different ways, but this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the above code worked partially for me but it was good help i juts replaced the contractor parameters as follows

const string PLINK_PATH = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe";

```
        Process p = new Process();

        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;           
        p.StartInfo.FileName = PLINK_PATH;            
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" -ssh {0}@{1} -pw {2}", userName, remoteHost, password);
```

Hope this helps with above code....