# Call LINUX-based binary from Windows and return output

Tags: linux, windows, command-line-interface

I am working on an integration project with a dependency on interfacing with a command-line binary/executable which only runs on a LINUX server.  I have no experience writing applications hosted on non-windows machines.  I would like to call the Linux-based application from a Windows Machine and return the output from the application.  I believe this could be done using PHP, NodeJS, etc... but I was curious if there are other alternatives for doing this.

Comment: the usual way to execute a command-line app on a remote Unix/Linux server is using a remote execution shell, such as `ssh`.

Comment: thanks isedev.  We actually ended up going that route calling the application using plink/putty using an SSH session and evoking it using the Process class in C#.  This thread was very helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028592/testing-using-plink-exe-to-connect-to-ssh-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

We ended up going with this approach of using putty/plink.

[Testing using Plink.exe to connect to SSH in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028592/testing-using-plink-exe-to-connect-to-ssh-in-c-sharp?rq=1)