# Sending Host name, Login Id & password dynamically to Putty using C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, putty

I am creating a utility in Windows with C# as a programming langugage.

Reqirement is

1. to create a connection with Unix Server -- i am trying to connect to Putty.exe
2. delete old files from specific location
3. copy new files to specific location.

Now, my question is how to pass "host name" + loginID & password to the putty dynamically.

```
     Process.Start(@"C:\Putty\putty.exe");
```

This is opening putty with configuration wizard, can i pass all the values in the command directly

Comment: try putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw yourpassword

Comment: When i am passing like  Process.Start(@"C:\Putty\putty.exe", -ssh user@host -mypassword); its throwing error

Comment: [what error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772059/sending-host-name-login-id-password-dynamically-to-putty-using-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment42125065_26772059)

Comment: [check this ready example using plink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028592/testing-using-plink-exe-to-connect-to-ssh-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Putty's command line arguments [here](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline) to pass that to Putty :

```
string hostname = "hostname";
string login = "login";
string password = "password";


ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Putty\putty.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}@{1} -pw {2}",login,hostname, password);
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Something like that should work...

Comment: can you also help me to delete the files from certain location once i logged in to putty. Say i have to delete all the files under Folder name NewFolder

Comment: Sounds like another question @Coder2014. You'd best make a new one if you really can't figure it out.

Comment: i have added in the requirement [second point] :) if you can help!!

Comment: Added new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773567/putty-delete-files-dynamically-using-c-sharp