# Putty - Delete files dynamically using C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, putty

I am working on a Windows app with C# as a programming langugage.

Requirement is

1. to login to putty dynamically
2. delete old files from specific location

I am currently using below code to login to putty, but how do i ran the delete command ??

```
string hostname = "hostname";
string login = "login";
string password = "password";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Putty\putty.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}@{1} -pw {2}", login, hostname, password);
startInfo.Start();
```

I want to pass something like this

```
rm myFile*.txt
```

But before that I have to navigate to particular location by

```
cd /dir1/dir2/NewFolder
```

I wanted to delete all the `.txt` files under NewFolder??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putty has the command line option [`-m {script_file}`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3.6) which allows you to specify a script file to be run against the remote server. After all the commands are run, putty will exit.

You could save the command to be run in a script file, call Putty, and delete the script file when you're done.

The following code works for me:

```
string hostname = "hostname";
string login = "login";
string password = "password";
string command = "rm ~/dir1/dir2/NewFolder/*.txt"; // modify this to suit your needs

const string scriptFileName = @"remote_commands.sh";
File.WriteAllText(scriptFileName, command);

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Putty\putty.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}@{1} -pw {2} -m {3}", 
                                     login, hostname, password, scriptFileName);

var process = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

File.Delete(scriptFileName);
```

If all you want to do is send a single command to the server, this solution will do. If you need more advanced functionality, like reading the server response, you should check out [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26774168/390819).

#### Edit:

Here's how to use plink to run commands and get their output:

```
string hostname = "hostname";
string login = "login";
string password = "password";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Putty\plink.exe";
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}@{1} -pw {2}",
                                        login, hostname, password);

using (var process = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo})
{
    process.Start();

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ls");
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo 'run more commands here...'");
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit"); // make sure we exit at the end

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: I am getting exception - "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables". [ while executing above code] -please help

Comment: @Coder2014 Don't know why; it worked perfectly for me. Try inserting `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` before the `new Process(...` line.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Is there any way to validate whether the command executed or not. i know you have mentioned to check Thomas answer. But while using that i am not able to get p.StandardOutput. can you help!!

Comment: @Coder2014 just tried it and it worked. Please see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps, because I can't try it right know, but it could lead you to the right direction. Try something like this:

```
string hostname = "hostname";
string login = "login";
string password = "password";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Putty\plink.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}@{1} -pw {2}", login, hostname, password);

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd /dir1/dir2/NewFolder");
```

You should try 'plink', which is the command line version of Putty. With `startInfo.RedirectStandardInput` you specify, that the you can write to the stdin of the process with `p.StandardInput.WriteLine()`. This is also available for stdout, so you can read the output of the process.

Comment: can you please help to get the standard output after executing command. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390559/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-system-diagnostics-process but it didnt helped

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question we should first make some things clear:

(1) You do not login to PuTTY. You use PuTTY to establish a connection to a remote server and to start a shell. Therefore you login to the server hostname

(2) PuTTY is a program to provide an interactive shell to the user. It is not intended to be used as an programming interface

What you look for is a SSH client library such as https://sshnet.codeplex.com/ (never used it, stated here as an example). Such libraries allow you to send commands using .NET using a predefined API