# Capturing Plink output in C#

Tags: c#, io, putty, plink

I am trying to use Plink to access information on a machine. I followed this tutorial:
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Creating-a-SSH-connection-using-plink-PuTTY-via-C-application-1760.ph

So far I am only using my program to just open up Plink, and I will be adding in the login information and such once I can at least get Plink to be openable in my program. I have this based on the tutorial:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd");
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;

Process process = Process.Start(psi);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
string cmdForTunnel = "plink";
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmdForTunnel);
process.WaitForExit();
Thread.Sleep(10000);

//DoBusinessLogic();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("logout");
Thread.Sleep(10000);

if (process.HasExited)
{
    process.Close();
    process.Dispose();
}
```

But nothing is displayed, which bothers me. The command `plink` is supposed to display the help information on how to use the program (I will be replacing the command with something more useful later), but the command prompt remains empty. I also experimented by replacing `plink` with `ipconfig`, which also displayed nothing.

I know how to open up cmd myself and type in `plink` to access it. I want to replicate this action in my program.

Comment: why don't you start plink instead of cmd?

Comment: Wouldn't strait up opening plink cause it to close instantly, since it is a comand line application?

Comment: I know how to open up cmd myself via start menu and type in plink to access it. I want my program to replicate this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many faults in your code:

- You are redirecting an output, and you are not reading/processing/printing it (that's why *"nothing is displayed"*)
- Running `plink` by "typing" `plink` to `cmd.exe` is insane. You can run `plink` directly, avoiding `cmd.exe` completely (and even if you needed to use the `cmd.exe`, you should pass `plink.exe` to it on a command-line: `/c path\plink.exe`). And no, running it directly would not cause Plink *to close instantly*.
- Calling `WaitForExit()` without reading the redirected output will deadlock your code once an output buffer fills. See *Remarks* section for [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput). Alternatively, use [`process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend) (it's like `WaitForExit`, but also reads the output). It's actually what the MSDN recommends in the previous link.
- If you are going to execute one command only, using Plink, it's also better to pass the command on Plink command-line, rather than "typing" it to its (redirected) input:

  ```
  plink.exe -ssh user@host command
  ```

See also answer to [Testing using Plink.exe to connect to SSH in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22028592/850848)

Comment: Alright then, how do I run it directly? I tried Console.WriteLine and it doesn't really execute the command. (If you can't tell, I am fairly new to C#. I am also not used to command line applications like my current project. As a game developer I am more used to working with interfaces.)

Comment: Use `plink.exe` in `ProcessStartInfo` constructor, instead of `cmd.exe`. See an accepted answer to the question I have linked to at the end of my answer.