# SQL query over SSH returning appended prompts

Tags: c#, sql, ssh, putty, plink

While running SQL query over SSH, return prompts are getting concatenated. While I run the query command manually thru cmd, I am getting them sequentially which is what I want to replicate in my code too. I am using plink to connect to the host, and have taken help from [Testing using Plink.exe to connect to SSH in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028592/testing-using-plink-exe-to-connect-to-ssh-in-c-sharp)

```
SQL> @acct_search_email
Enter value for acc_number: 9999999998
Enter value for site_code: CAR
```

---

```
SQL> @acct_search_email
SQL> Enter value for acct_number: Enter value for site_code: 999999998
```

Comment: The first image is the desired output that I want to reproduce thru the code, the second one is the one that I am currently getting.

Comment: 1) Show us your code 2) Even better, do not use Plink to implement SSH. Use some .NET SSH library. Like SSH.NET.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I have moved onto Bluezone. Will see if that works.